# Is it possible to build Eigen lib for C++ instead of using pre-built files?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using pre-built 3.2.5 Eigen lib files, downloaded from website:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

I heard if I built the files by myself on my PC I could achieve higher compatibility with my processor what would lead to slight increase of lib's performance. Currently I am struggling with eigensolver calculation time being too long.

I use Visual Studio 2005 and I just add Eigen files location to my projects properties linker.

Is there any way to build those files myself on my platform? I am a bit confused how could I do it. Is it related to CMake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no library to build, as Eigen is a "pure template header library". From the main [site](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Requirements):

> Requirements
>
> Eigen doesn't have any dependencies other than the C++ standard
>   library.
>
> We use the CMake build system, but only to build the documentation and
>   unit-tests, and to automate installation. If you just want to use
>   Eigen, you can use the header files right away. There is no binary
>   library to link to, and no configured header file. Eigen is a pure
>   template library defined in the headers.

You don't need to add the files location to the linker, but to the (additional) included directories in your project or to a property sheet.

Regarding calculation time, make sure you're running in Release and not Debug. There is a difference of about 100 in the speed. Also, make sure that optimizations are turned on (/O2 or /Ox).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well I am running in Release mode and O2 optimization is turned on. I will try Ox but I do not expect much change. Other thing is I tried to play a bit with Eigen multi-threading but no result. I think I will need to switch to MKL. As I have MKL 7.1 I can't wrap it together with Eigen (it is possible if MKL is 10.3 + from what I've read).

Comment: Regarding multithreading, just make sure you have /OpenMP enabled. That should allow Eigen to use it.

Comment: Actually I am a bit confused because I have created a different thread that is responsible for some DSP calculations. There I use Eigen matrices and Eigensolver - it's only place in my code where I use Eigen. But as Eigensolver calculation takes too much time it affects sometimes my other thread which is responsible for copying data to audio output. Threads are unrelated... when I use Eigen::nbThreads(); I get response 1. I wonder if I should use multithreading for Eigen in this case. Of course I am not using it in main thread but still only in one thread, nowhere else.

Comment: Is there a way to create a `lib` for static linking from Eigen?

Comment: @Royi Hypothetically, you can try and wrap Eigen, but that's kinda futile. You'd have to take every type of expression combination you might ever want and create it. Much easier to just to include the header files.

Comment: @AviGinsburg, My rational is I want to have MKL integrated into Eigen only once.